# Update Markers on the basis of selected DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, laravel-5

Hi everyone I am trying to update markers on the basis of selected category, In alert I am getting the selected dropdown Now am trying to pass the selected value into google map to filter markers.please guide me, I need help

HTML:

```
 <select id="property_id" name="property_type" onchange="property_type(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
        <option selected>Property Type</option>
        <option value="Single_Family_Home">Single Family Home</option>
        <option value="Multi_Family_Home">Multi Family Home</option>
        <option value="Condominium">Condominium</option>
        <option value="Townhome">Townhome</option>
 </select>
```

Google Map Javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 //globally declared the array and variables
  var pubvar1 = 0;
  var pubvar2 = 0;
  var locations = [];
</script>

@foreach($row as $val)
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    pubvar1++;

    //Fetching longitude and latitude and other details from database 
    locations[pubvar1] = {lat: {{$val->lat}}, lng: {{$val->log}}, id: {{$val->id}},adr: "{{$val->address}}", psz: "{{$val->property_size}}", img: "{{$val->image}}", state: "{{$val->state}}", city: "{{$val->city}}", property_type: "{{$val->property_type}}"};

    //alert(locations[pubvar1].property_type);

 </script>
@endforeach  

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var geocoder;
        function InitializeMap() {

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(13.0827, 80.2707);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom : 7,
                center : latlng,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI : false
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        }
        //window.onload = InitializeMap;

 function property_type(selectControl)   {
    //here I am getting the Selected Dropdown
    alert(selectControl);
  }

        $(window).load(function() {         
            loadLocation();         
        });

        function loadLocation() {
                $.urlParam = function(name) {
                var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
                return results[1] || 0;
                }
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            InitializeMap();
            var address = $.urlParam('address');
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address' : address
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map : map,
                        icon : 'hidden',

                        position : results[0].geometry.location
                    }); 

                   // Add circle overlay and bind to marker
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    radius: 250000,    // metres
                    fillColor: '#00BFFF',
                    strokeColor: '#04bce0'


                    });
                    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

                    // Multiple Markers
                    // Display multiple markers on a map
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                    for(var i=1; i<=pubvar1; i++){

                        myLatLng = {lat: locations[i].lat, lng: locations[i].lng};
                        var html = "<div><br><b>Address</b>:"+locations[i].adr+",<br>"+locations[i].city+","+locations[i].state+"<br><b>Property Size</b>:"+locations[i].psz+"<br><img style='height:80px; width:150px;' src='images/test/"+locations[i].img+"' /><br> <a href=property_details?id"+locations[i].adr+"><b>More Details</b></a></div>" ;
                        //alert(html);
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatLng,
                            map: map,
                            title: 'Hello World!',
                            icon: 'images/marker.png'
                        });
                        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);                                      
                    }   

                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        }
```

Comment: You can reset the Markers (remove them all) and then add the markers again when the dropdown value changes. You already have the array, its just a matter of retrieving the value the objects, and adding the necessary Markers in them.

Comment: Thanxx for reply I am getting all the value from database now I am trying to pass into map into how can I pass and filter.  suggest something in my code, please bear with me I am new to google map